# Change value of React final form Field, when state of outer component changes

Tags: react-final-form

I am trying to change value of react-final-form Field, whenever event from outer component occurs. 
Let´s say I call server API, which eventually changes state object. This object was the initialValues for an origin form, but of course Form has its own state managment, so changing this outer state doesnt affect the Field´s value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the use case, but if you change the value passed to `<Form/>`'s `initialValues` prop, the form will reinitialize to those values.

Comment: Hi Eric. Could you please help me with my same problem? I can't find any solution for "change one form from another form". For example: i have 2 forms made with react-final-form. The 1 form Field can be changed from my second form.

I tried next things:
1) write it into the redux store on every form values changing, and used this info as initialValues of my form. In that case there is a problem. Form is overwriting form values and reset the form state and a lot of other problems
2) write "form" actions (as "change", "focus", "initialize") into redux store and use in the right place.